# Adding view onto Window of Twitter

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter, uiwindow

Hi i am facing a strange problem. I have a class which is `NSObject` type, and on same class i want to share image on Facebook and Email and also on Twitter. I successfully done FB and Email, On Email i use `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]  addSubview:mailer.view];` to show Mail controller onto Window instread of Presenting Model view controller and same as on Dismiss i use Remove from super view. But when i do same with twitter controller then twitter controller just show me few mili seconds and then hide. I also add new View controller onto Window and then Present its controller onto that View controller but same output. Don't know what going wrong. Please help on that. Thanks in advance. This will be great for me :)

**Edited**

```
 if (_engine != nil) {
    _engine = nil;
    [_engine release];
}    
_engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
_engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
_engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;

UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate: self];

if (controller) {
    NSLog(@"Sharing on Twitter on loading controller of twitter");
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:controller.view];

}
else {
    NSLog(@"Sharing on Twitter in else condition");
    [self sharetoTwitter:screenImg];
}
```

**ShareToTwitterMethod**

```
- (void) sharetoTwitter:(UIImage *)img {
NSString *response = [_engine _uploadImage:img requestType:MGTwitterPublicTimelineRequest responseType:MGTwitterStatus]; 
NSLog(@"twitter post notification");
}
```

I used Add subview to load view instead of Presenting View.

Comment: post some more code so that's easier to help you

Comment: What exactly you want to see in code. I am doing same to load twitter view. just few change i use addsubview instead of presenting view. Check my Edited Question i add code to load view of twitter.

Comment: It's a very bad way of displaying a view since you're messing with ownerships of ViewController. Why aren't you ok with a modal presentation in the first place?

Comment: Actually i am developing a Unity application, and integrating unity with xcode so after compiling unity give me NSObject type class, so i am bound to do like this. As i mentioned that i added a viewcontroller onto Window then present twitter controller but same output. Don't know how to tackle with this. If you know or any idea kindly help me on this. Thanks

Comment: please post sharetoTwitter method code

Comment: Updated my code, with Share to Twitter Method.

Comment: Have you checked Unity Dev Network? For example: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/40494/who-can-help-me-how-to-get-the-view-controlleruivi.html

Comment: Yeah, This also helped me to find solution. Aaaaah Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window addSubView:controller.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];//important line dont forget to set this line
```

Comment: Thanks Sumanth, i got answer. Just bit change in your code and load twitter controller.
Here is what i do.
 UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        window.rootViewController = controller;

Comment: rootViewController will not work before iOS 4. but addSubView/rootViewController are almost same to use.

Comment: Yes, Now getting issue to Remove this, I am doing like this to remove.
 [controller removeFromParentViewController];. Is it Ok, or should i use some thing else because its not working.

Comment: Worked, Simply do [controller.view removeFromSuperview];
How silly i am :p